# On-demand popup in a Crossrider extension

Tags: crossrider

I am looking for a way to display an on-demand pop in a Crossrider extension, in the same fassion as the Javascript 'confirm' dialog. I have an HTML page in the resources and I would like to use it in a popup, which will be displayed whenever a certain message is dispatched. I realize there is functionality to display popups in Crossrider (appAPI.browserAction.setPopup), however I would like to display a custom popup on-demand, instead of a simple JS 'confirm' dialog.  Is there a way of doing that?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [appAPI.browserAction.setPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setPopup) and [appAPI.browserAction.clearPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-clearPopup) to control the popup. In the following example, the extension scope code determines which popup is required based on the page visited and sets it accordingly:

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    if (appAPI.isMatchPages("*google", "*msn")) {
        // Send message to background to set the popup based on the page url
        appAPI.message.toBackground({
            request: 'set-popup',
            popup: (location.hostname.indexOf('google') !== -1)
                ? 'google.html'
                : 'msn.html'
        });
    } else {
        // Send message to background to clear the popup for other pages
        appAPI.message.toBackground({
            request: 'clear-popup'
        });
    }
});
```

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icon.jpg');
    appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
        switch(msg.request) {
            case 'set-popup':
                // When setting the page, first clear the existing popup
                appAPI.browserAction.clearPopup();
                // then set the new popup
                appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({
                    resourcePath: msg.popup,
                    width: 300,
                    height: 200
                });
                break;
            case 'clear-popup':
                appAPI.browserAction.clearPopup();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesn't look like the actual popup is being displayed. I made sure the message 'set-popup' is being received in background.js, but the actual popup (added a page MyPopup.html) from the resources is not being displayed. Does appAPI.browserAction.setPopup actually display the popup or just sets the popup properties? Can I trigger the popup to display without clicking the browser button for the extension? Thank you.

Comment: I actually found a workaround. I ended up creating my own custom DIV inside extension.js and using that as a popup whenever needed. It is not the prettiest solution, but seems to work so far. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Regarding the browserAction popup, it is by definition a button and hence only displays when the button is clicked. From your second response, it appeard that you are after a popup that you can show on demand. You workaround is the generally accepted method of achieving your goal. You can also use our Notifications plugin for this purpose or a third party JavaScript library as some developers do. Hope that helps.